# Computing matrix determinant in Solidity

Tags: solidity, arrays

I am trying to write a solidity contract to compute Matrix determinant. 
I am following the C++ implementation from here: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-compute-determinant-of-a-matrix

The following code works fine up to a square matrix of size 5. But when the size increases it fails to compute. 
I have also increased the gas limit in Remix and tried to run but still, it fails.
(Also tried to run using Web3 provider - Ganache with an increased gas limit, but ganache crashed/failed to run.)
I am looking to implement it for Matrix sizes **12 to 15**.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

I have attached my code below:

```
contract Determinant {
  uint [5][5] public matA = [[1,1,2,1,2],[3,0,0,5,4],[2,1,4,3,1],[1,0,5,0,7],[4,2,5,4,3]];
  uint public matrix_order;
  int256 public output = 0;
  uint [5] public temp_output;

function compute () public {
    matrix_order = matA.length;
    output = determinantOfMatrix(matA, matrix_order);
}

function determinantOfMatrix (uint[5][5] memory mat1, uint _order) private returns (int256) {
    uint [5][5] memory submatrix;
    int256 det = 0;
    uint256 sign = 1;
    int256 result;

    if (_order == 2)
        return int256((mat1[0][0] * mat1[1][1]) - (mat1[1][0] * mat1[0][1]));
    else {
        for (uint x = 0; x < _order; x++){
            uint subi = 0;
            for (uint i = 1; i< _order; i++){
                uint subj = 0;
                for(uint j = 0; j<_order; j++){
                    if (j != x){
                        submatrix[subi][subj] = mat1[i][j];
                        subj++;
                    }
                }
                subi++;
            }
            result = int256((-sign) ** x);
            temp_output[x] = mat1[0][x] * uint(determinantOfMatrix (submatrix, _order - 1 ));
            det = det + result * int256(temp_output[x]);
        }
        return det;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error do you get? Solidity is not ideal to do intensive mathematics or any other complex task. Some resources like memory is very constrained.

Comment: `-sign ** x`? Are you sure you didn't mean `(-sign) ** x`?

Comment: Also, since your function is recursive, it is prone to revert quickly as the size of your input grows. Think of blockchain programming as similar to RT/embedded programming in that sense. Your resources are very limited. Recursion is a hard stack consumer, which you want to avoid when possible.

Comment: Last note - you are not checking for overflows (as a result of `+` or `*`) and underflows (as a result of `-`) anywhere in your code. That by itself could lead to incorrect results very easily.

Comment: @Ismael I am not getting any specific error. What is happening is- Remix hangs when I try to execute the Compute function and the same thing happens for Ganache. Can you please suggest how can I execute this code at least for matrix size 10? Thanks

Comment: @goodvibration Actually I am learning Solidity by implementation. So this code is probably not the ideal one. Can you please suggest what can I do to make it a good example and also running for at least of matrix size 10? Thanks.

Comment: You still need to explain `result = int256(-sign ** x)`. In your code, it is always equal to `-1`, so I suspect that your code gives the wrong result even if we manage to make it work for a matrix size of 10.

Comment: @goodvibration Actually I tried to implement "pow(-1, x)" by (-sign**x) from the referenced c++ code in tutorialspoint. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: So you should most definitely use `(-sign) ** x` and not `-sign ** x`!!!

Comment: After improving some of your code, I too haven't been able to run it for more than 6 without reverting. For 6, I always get zero so I suspect that there's a problem with that as well (though perhaps it is a purely computational problem, for example, due to overflows or underflows as I've mentioned above). In short, you'll need to change your implementation from recursive to iterative

Comment: @NB18 In general I'd recommend to avoid any intensive computation, and if possible use smart contracts to verify the result. Obviously it depends on the problem you are trying to solve. Possible approaches I will try in this case: receive determinant as parameter, require diagonal matrix, LU decomposed matrix.